# Indirect recursive generic type definitions in scala

Tags: scala, generics, recursion

Direct type recursion just works:

```
trait TT[T<:TT[T]]
```

But I can made indirect one with naive approach

```
trait UU[V <: VV[UU[V]]]
trait VV[U <: UU[VV[U]]]
```

give me error:

```
CyclicTraits.scala:23: error: type arguments [UU[V]] do not conform to
    trait VV's type parameter bounds [U <: UU[VV[U]]]
trait UU[V <: VV[UU[V]]]
              ^
CyclicTraits.scala:25: error: type arguments [VV[U]] do not conform to
    trait UU's type parameter bounds [V <: VV[UU[V]]]
trait VV[U <: UU[VV[U]]]
              ^
```

How should indirect type parameter recursion be expressed properly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem here isn't the recursion—it is actually a matter of the type parameters not conforming to the bounds, as the error message says. Your example works perfectly if you make the parameters covariant:

```
trait UU[+V <: VV[UU[V]]]
trait VV[+U <: UU[VV[U]]]
```

In your version (without the covariance), the fact that `V` is a subtype of `VV[UU[V]]` tells us nothing about whether or not `UU[V]` is a subtype of `UU[VV[UU[V]]]`, so we get the conformance error. If the type parameters are covariant, we know that `V` being a subtype of `VV[UU[V]]` entails that `UU[V]` is a subtype of `UU[VV[UU[V]]]`, and everything's fine.