# Has Scala a better way to express "self recursive generic types"?

Tags: scala, generics, recursion, type-safety

There's a common Java idiom (seen in `Enum` for example) to declare a generic type variable that has to match the actual derived type.

```
class Enum<E extends Enum<E>> {
...
}
```

or, if needed more generic arguments:

```
abstract class Foo<T, Actual extends Foo<T, Actual>> {
    //now we can refer to the actual type
    abstract Actual copy();
}
class Concrete<T> extends Foo<T, Concrete<T>> {
    Concrete<T> copy() {...}
}
```

Things can get very verbose really quickly, so  I imagined that Scala might have something nicer than a literal translation of the examples above.

Are there any more elegant ways to achieve this?

Comment: "There's a common Java idiom" It's not common. The bounds on `Actual` in your example do not appear to serve any useful purpose -- replacing it with `abstract class Foo<T, Actual>` would work just as well.

Comment: It starts to be common once you get picky about static type safety. `abstract class Foo<T, Actual>` does not enforce any type on `Actual`, it would allow something like `class Concrete<T> extends Foo<T, String> { String copy() {...}}` and that is not what was meant.

Comment: Your bounds do not add any static type safety as written above. People who use such bounds are almost always mistaken. "it would allow something like" Yes, and it is perfectly type-safe as written. Generics are only useful where they add additional type safety, allowing you to do something that would require casts otherwise. Can you think of an example where your bounds allow some code to be safely done without casts and my bounds do not?

Comment: It is difficult find a good example that fits here, but they are necessary if you don't want your types to *decay* to a common denominator and want the actual error happening where it is supposed to happen (in the declaration of the derived class) and not far away from the cause (when the method using the `Actual` type is invoked).

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. Why should there be any "error" at all? If it's "common" as you say you should be able to find a simple example. I don't think there is one.

Comment: Are you saying that `Enum` is not common enough? My time is too valuable to be wasted trying to explain anything to someone that is clearly intelligent enough to understand it for himself but doesn't want to.

Comment: `Enum` is a special case because enum types are generated by the language, not the user. Most people try to do so-called "self recursive generic types" for a generic class in order to try to do something like "self type", i.e. the type of the implementing class. However, that is not possible to do with Generics in Java, and they ultimately need to use an unsafe cast, and it is possible to provide examples where the cast will fail. So this scheme is fundamentally unsafe, and if you use it in a "safe" way, it is completely equivalent to not having recursive bounds.

Comment: You should be extremely careful when using self-bounds even in Java. In your example, `Concrete` should be final to prevent breaking `Foo`'s contracts in any other subtypes of `Concrete`. See more details here: http://blog.jooq.org/2013/06/28/the-dangers-of-correlating-subtype-polymorphism-with-generic-polymorphism

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871731/indirect-recursive-generic-type-definitions-in-scala

Comment: I'll read the post, looks interesting @LukasEder

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An alternative formulation is to use abstract type members:

```
trait Foo { self => 
  type A <: Foo {type A = self.A}
}
```

With your example:

```
trait Foo { self =>
  type T
  type Actual <: Foo {type T = self.T; type Actual = self.Actual}
}

trait Concrete extends Foo { self =>
  type T
  type Actual = Concrete {type T = self.T}
}
```

While this reformulation isn't really nicer at the trait/class declarations, when using the traits/classes it can be much terser. (And as far as I know, there isn't another way to reformulate recursive types).

Comment: looks interesting, I still have lots of things to learn about Scala!

Comment: We can break it: https://gist.github.com/frozenspider/938991752d59d07927db Here, for `FooExtLvl1` self-type points to its child, and for `FooExtLvl3` - to its parent. First case is rarely a desired effect.